# What happens if SQL Server mirroring fails over and during synchronisation?

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

I have two sql boxes, one primary and one mirror.

The mirror stopped synchronising last night for about 12 hours and so now the primary is transferring about 25GB of logs that built up.

However it's taking a long time.

What happens if the primary falls over (for whatever reason) during this time? Presumably the mirror will take over as primary, but I don't know how much of the transaction logs have been transferred.

Comment: IIRC, it won't allow you to fail over (without *explicit* intervention) until the mirror is in a synchronized state.